# ms-access query with link fields of different types

Tags: ms-access, pass-through

I am trying to create a pass-through query in ms-access where the linking fileds are 'TEXT' type and 'MEMO' type. I have successfully complete this as an ms-access Select query but when I convert to a pass through I get a message saying that the fields cannot be bound. Can anyone please help me with this?

In the code below document_num and info_card_id are 'TEXT', packet_nm and infocardid1 are both 'MEMO'

Unfortunatly I cannot change the data types in their respective tables as I am using ODBC connections to a proprietary database application.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT     dbo.tdc_doc_infocard.document_num,
                        dbo.v_packets.packet_nm,
                        dbo.v_packets.step_name,
                        dbo.v_packets.step_order,
                        dbo.dataset_669CEFB3DD54420FB4.TXTNCRDETAILS1
    FROM                dbo.v_packets,
                        dbo.dataset_669CEFB3DD54420FB4,
                        dbo.tdc_doc_infocard
    WHERE               (dbo.tdc_doc_infocard.document_num=dbo.v_packets.packet_nm) AND
                        (dbo.tdc_doc_infocard.info_card_id=dbo.dataset_669CEFB3DD54420FB4.INFOCARDID1)
    ORDER BY            dbo.tdc_doc_infocard.document_num;
```

[Error message link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG9ad.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dbo_" prefix used in Access should be "dbo."

And I believe `[dbo.v_packets]` should read: `dbo.v_packets`.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, when I created the pass-through query I changed from dbo_ to dbo. before trying it but it still encountered the 'cannot be bound' error.

Comment: Then please correct your posted code to reflect the actual code used.

Comment: Hi Gustav, I have updated the Code used in the pass-through query

Comment: Many thanks Gustav. I also removed the [ ] from the other WHERE criteria and the query ran as it should.